# Import Point Cloud to Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, point-clouds

We are looking into ways to import Reality Capture into Forge Viewer Environment (e.g., Point Cloud and/or 360-degree site images).

We have currently tried to import Point Cloud (.RCS format) to Forge Viewer, but are not able to.

Answer (score 0):

This extension may be starting point
https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-extensions/tree/main/public/extensions/PotreeExtension